# Inverse, modulo m, of power $a^m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My text defines the inverse modulo m as follows:

If $gcd(a,m)=1$ then $a^{-1}$ is the residue of the solution x, (reduced modulo m), of the congruence $ax\equiv 1 \pmod{m}$.

It states without explanation that the equation

$(a^n)^{-1}\equiv (a^{-1})^n$ can be proved by induction.

The induction base is the tautology $a^{-1} \equiv a^{-1}$

The induction hypothesis is

"For any x and y satisfying $a^n x \equiv 1$ and $ay\equiv 1$, $x\equiv y^n$"

The induction step to be proven would be

"For any p and q satisfying $a^{n+1} p \equiv 1$ and $aq\equiv 1$, $p\equiv q^{n+1}$"

Choose $x=ap$ and $y=q$. Then $ap\equiv q^n$ and $p\equiv a^{-1}q^n$

But $a^{-1}\equiv q$, so $p\equiv q^{n+1}$

Is this proof valid?

Answer (score 1):

This assertion holds in more general terms. If $R$ is a commutative ring and $a\in R$ is invertible, then for each $n\geq 0$, $a^{-n} := (a^{-1})^n$ is invertible.

Its clear for $n=1$.
Suppose $a^{-n}$ is invertible for $n\geq 1$, i.e., $a^{-n}b=1$ for some $b\in R$. Then $a^{-1}= a^{-1}(a^{-n}b) = a^{-(n+1)}b$ and so by multiplying with $a$ from the right, $a^{-(n+1)}(ba)=1$, i.e., $a^{-(n+1)}$ is invertible

Comment: Is my proof valid?

Comment: I understand that you have proved that a solution to $(a^{-1})^nx\equiv 1$ exists, but I do not see how that relates to the lhs of the proposition, namely $(a^n)^{-1}$ (the solution to $(a^n)y\equiv 1$). Understand that the proposition was given in the text to start a discussion of the concept of inverse. It does not assume *any* properties of inverses beyond the definition of $a^{-1}$. In particular, there is no concept of $a^{-n}$ for $n\ne1$ And I am still wanting the answer to my original question, i.e. is *my* proof valid?

Answer (score 0):

I think it boils down to proving that $a^n(a^{-1})^n\equiv 1$. That would be the induction hypothesis, and multiplying be $a a^{-1}$ gives $a^{-(n+1)}a^{n+1}\equiv 1$